# Is there a way to disable/hide "Re-execute promotion" button

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to disable/hide "Re-execute promotion" button for the builds in cases like -
Build has been promoted successfully once.
Build promoted by one user should not be re-executable by another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Force Promotion" and "Re-execute Promotion" buttons are only visible to those with full admin permission for the job. A general user should not have such permissions, and will not see those buttons.

A general user should be configured in the promotion settings (who can trigger it), and they will only see "Approve" button, once.

Comment: I have an LDAP group configured with 'Read' and 'Discover' permissions through 'Enable project-based security'. And, I have the same group configured for 'Only when manually approved' approvers. Now, whenever the job is built, members of this group can see the 'Approve' button, and if anyone approves it, then the actions get executed fine, but then appears the 'Re-execute Promotion' button. Could you please let know if I am missing/misconfiguring anything?

Comment: Double check that whichever account you are checking from is **only** member of that group, and not a member of some other group that gives admin permissions as well (such as yourself). From what you described, the user should not see anything besides the "Approve" button, unless the user's permissions are coming from some dual-group membership (or other individual permissions)

Comment: Thanks @Slav.. Although I did not manage to get 'Re-execute Promotion' button hidden/disabled, but I could see that trying to re-execute actually takes the approver to an empty page and no repeat promotion happens. Not sure if it's plugin UI issue that the button is always displayed.